# Random HTTP 500 error Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I've been having an issue with a HTTP 500 error. It doesn't seem to cause any real problems until a few hours after the error has been shown. After the error shows up the script begins to act abnormally, giving hangups on controlling a relay and degrading in response time.

I checked my logs both in the pi and the server side and below is what I found but I can't figure out what my issue is since it seems so random, the HTTP request typically returns a 200 status and runs fine.

On the pi:

tail applocation/errors.log

```
2018-03-05 06:38:33 [HTTP Error]    While sending data to remote Server: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
2018-03-05 09:08:50 [HTTP Error]    While sending data to remote Server: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

on the server:

This is where it gets weird because most of the time it returns 200 but like I said every so often it gives a 500 error.

cat /var/log/ngnix/access.log | grep 9:0

```
47.176.12.130 - - [05/Mar/2018:09:08:29 -0800] "POST /api/1.0/access/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "-" "Python-urllib/3.4"
47.176.12.130 - - [05/Mar/2018:09:08:50 -0800] "POST /api/1.0/access/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "-" "Python-urllib/3.4"
47.176.12.130 - - [05/Mar/2018:09:09:28 -0800] "POST /api/1.0/access/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "-" "Python-urllib/3.4"
```

cat /var/log/ngnix/access.log | grep 500

```
raspberry.pi.ip - - [05/Mar/2018:06:38:33 -0800] "POST /api/1.0/access/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "-" "Python-urllib/3.4"
raspberry.pi.ip - - [05/Mar/2018:09:08:50 -0800] "POST /api/1.0/access/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "-" "Python-urllib/3.4"
```

in my urls.py inside my API:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^1.0/access/add/$', views.access_add, name='access_add'),
    url(r'^1.0/employees/active/$', views.employees_active, name='employees_active'),
]
```

in my views.py inside my API:

```
@csrf_exempt
def access_add(request):
    context = {
        'status': 'error',
        'msg' : ''
    }

    if request.method != 'POST':
        context["msg"] = "This method only supports POST"
        return JsonResponse(context)

    try:
        content = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    except Exception as e:
        context['msg'] = "Failed to load JSON parameters."
        return JsonResponse(context)

    key = content.get('key')
    gate = content.get('gate')
    code = content.get('code')

    if key != KEY:
        context['msg'] = "Please provide a valid API key."
        return JsonResponse(context)

    if gate not in ['entry','exit']:
        context['msg'] = "Please provide a valid gate name."
        return JsonResponse(context)

    gate = 1 if gate == "entry" else 2

    if not code:
        context['msg'] = "Please provide an access code."
        return JsonResponse(context)

    context['status'] = "success"

    try:
        employee = Employee.objects.get(code=code)
        Eventlog.objects.create(event=gate, employee=employee, status=True)
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            Eventlog.objects.create(event=gate, status=False)
        except:
            pass

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

Comment: In the browser console's networking tab, can you click on the request that is giving the 500 and click on the "Response" tab? Does the server give some error there?

Comment: If `DEBUG` is `False` then Django should send your site admins an email with the full traceback. Some things to consider: what if `content = json.loads(...)` doesn't return a dictionary? Could `Eventlog.objects.create()` raise an exception? Could `Employee.objects.get(code=code)` raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`?

Comment: You can also change the error logging to for example log tracebacks to a log file, or hook up an error tracking service such as sentry.io or rollbar.com